# Change the following event from user control to viewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I need to move this event from the user control to the viewModel,I have read the following link 
 but not sure that I got it since command are true or false,my question is assume that I have the following event 
 how should I change it to the viewModel.?

Please assist ,Im really stuck !!!!

http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/30/handling-events-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/

```
     private void DropText_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
     {
         var textBox = (TextBox) sender;
         if (textBox == null) return;
         textBox.Focus();
         var dataObject = new DataObject((textBox).Text);
         dataObject.SetData(DragSource, sender);
         DragDrop.DoDragDrop(textBox, dataObject, DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move);
     }



  <TextBox x:Name="Job"  
                    AcceptsReturn="True"
                    AllowDrop="True" 
                    PreviewMouseDown="DropText_PreviewMouseDown"
                    SelectionChanged="listbox_SelectionChanged"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 





internal class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    readonly Action _execute;
    readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute();
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            if (_canExecute != null)
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            if (_canExecute != null)
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute();
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChange;
    public void RaiseCanExecuteChange()
        {
        if (CanExecuteChange != null)
            CanExecuteChange(this, new EventArgs());
        }
```

Comment: You can use interaction triggers like specified in the link you posted in question.

Comment: @RohitVats,thanks, I was tried without success,can you please provide example for this specific event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your example with event triggers defined in the xaml. PreviewMouseDownCommand and SelectionChangedCommand are RelayCommands that will need to be declared in your viewmodel.

```
<TextBox  x:Name="Job"  
          AcceptsReturn="True"
          AllowDrop="True" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"> 
          <i:Interaction.Triggers>
              <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDown" >
                  <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PreviewMouseDownCommand}" />
              </i:EventTrigger>
              <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged" >
                  <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}" />
              </i:EventTrigger>
          </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

You will need a reference to System.Windows.Interactivity in order to use event triggers. Add this to the namespace declarations in your window:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```